# Reactjs firebase google authentication showing project id instead of Public-facing name

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

In my reactjs project, I use firebase 9.6.11 for email, google and facebook authentication.

When I call the signInWithPopup() and google sign in form, Sign in
to continue to show projectid.firebaseapp.com. I have already update Public-facing name at firebase's project setting.

Even though I have add custom domain, google sign in for redirect link also using projectid.firebaseapp.com url.

My project is hosting on firebase hosing and link with web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone facing this issue, please follow the step in here [Step to change custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?authuser=0)

For me, I forgot to enter OAuth 2.0 Client IDs's redirect url